# Resize an Image Display

Tags: html, css

I do not display it as a thumbnail, but can CSS help compress the image of size 1000x1000 into an image of size 500x500?

My CSS for the image looks like this:

```
.images {
  background:url("image.png") no-repeat scroll; // this is a 1000x1000 sized image
}
```

How do I overwrite this? I do not want to have to generate another image of size 500x500.

Comment: Cant you just put it in a container div instead?

Comment: What's your server-side language?

Comment: @jtheman I am newb, please explain more, I need to learn

Comment: See toshs answer below. If you absolute position either the img or a div containing the image, and set the size to 500x500 (is done in CSS) then you can fake the image to work as a background but control the size...

Comment: Sorry oriol has the solution below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size):

```
.images{
    background:url("image.png") no-repeat scroll;
    background-size:500px 500px;
}
```

But that will resize the image **AFTER** it has been dowloaded. And the best way is resizing the image with PHP (or similar) **BEFORE** the user downoads it.

If you can't resize it server-side and you want it to be cross-browser, you could also use

HTML:

```
<div class="images">
    <img class="bg" src="image.png" alt="My image" />
    Content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.images{
   position:relative;
}
.images>.bg{
   height:500px;
   width:500px;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:-1;
}
```

(You can set both `height` and `width` but only one of them is necessary).

Answer (score 2):

```
background-size: 500px 500px;
```

But it's not supported in ie7 and ie8.

If you would display it in an image tag you can set the width and height to the image tag. You can fake a background by absolute positioning the image.

```
<img width="500" src="..." />
```

If you are already using the image somewhere else it could be a good idea to reuse and resize it.

Comment: I also would want to display it in an img tag but I can't overwrite it with media query

Comment: set the image width to 100% and change the parent div with a media query